# How to change webpart zone index using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I have used the below code for change the web part properties.how to change the web part zone index in existing web part in the page?
My code is :

```
 $pagePath = "Pages/default.aspx"
    $pageUrl = $SiteURL + $pagePath
    $web = Get-SPWeb $SiteURL
    $PublishingWeb=[Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)
    $Page = $PublishingWeb.GetPublishingPages()

    $Page.CheckOut()
    $spWebPartManager = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($pageUrl, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)

    foreach ($webpart in ($spWebPartManager.WebParts | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq "Sample Name"}))
    {
     $spWebPartManager.SaveChanges($webpart);  
     break;
    }
$Page.CheckIn("checkin")
```

Suggest any idea.

Answer (score 3):

Use [SPLimitedWebPartManager.MoveWebPart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.splimitedwebpartmanager.movewebpart.aspx) to move the webpart to new zone or index. Example:

```
$zoneId = "5"
$zoneIndex = "NewOrOldZone"
$spWebPartManager.MoveWebPart($webpart, zoneId, zoneIndex);
$spWebPartManager.SaveChanges($webpart);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

```
$pagePath = "Pages/default.aspx"
$pageUrl = $SiteURL + $pagePath
$web = Get-SPWeb $SiteURL
$PublishingWeb=[Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)
$Page = $PublishingWeb.GetPublishingPages()

$Page.CheckOut()
$spWebPartManager = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($pageUrl, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)

$wp = $spWebPartManager.WebParts | Where-Object { $_.Title -eq "Sample Name" }
#change the zone according to that in your layout
$wp.ZoneID = "MiddleZone" 
$spWebPartManager.SaveChanges($wp)
$Page.CheckIn("checkin",[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPCheckinType]::MajorCheckIn)
$web.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at these blogs

http://www.kentd.com/2013/03/06/update-web-part-on-a-page-using-powershell-in-sharepoint-2010/

http://www.sites.se/2013/04/webpart-powershell-sharepoint-2013/

Hope it will give you an Idea. Please let me know if this helps.